# How can I subtract all given numbers in function with *args in python?

Tags: python, function, numpy, subtraction

I'm trying to make a 'subtract' function in Python that will take in any amount of numbers and subtract them. I tried using Numpy's 'subtract' function, but I got an error that states:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/Desktop/Python/Calculator/calculator_test.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(subtract(100, 6))  # Should return 94
  File "/Users/myname/Desktop/Python/Calculaotr/calculator_test.py", line 14, in subtract
    return np.subtract(numbers)  # - This isn't working
ValueError: invalid number of arguments
```

### My Code:

```
from math import prod
import numpy as np


# Simple calculator app

# Add function
def add(*numbers):
    return sum(numbers)


# Subtract function
def subtract(*numbers):
    return np.subtract(numbers)  # - This isn't working


# Multiply function
def multiply(*numbers):
    return prod(numbers)


# Divide function
def divide(*numbers):
    return


print(subtract(100, 6))  # Should return 94
```

### Version Info:

Python 3.9.4 (Python Version)

macOS BigSur 11.3 (Os version)

PyCharm CE 2021.1 (Code editor)

Comment: Try unpacking `numbers` when passing it into `subtract`

Comment: So, if you call `subtract(100,10,5,10,5)`, what's the answer?  There is no definitive answer to that.  Is it 100-10-5-10-5?  Then clearly you need `numbers[0] - sum(numbers[1:])`.

Comment: When you say "add a list of numbers", that makes sense.  There is one universal interpretation.  When you say "subtract a list of numbers", there isn't.  Subtract it from what?  Similarly, "multiply a list of numbers" is unambiguous.  "Divide a list of numbers" is not.  That's just not an operation people do.

Comment: Adding to what Tim Roberts says, np.subtract takes as input two arrays, and does element wise subtraction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `functools.reduce` paired with either `operator.sub` for subtraction or `operator.truediv` for division:

```py
from operator import sub, truediv
from functools import reduce


def divide(*numbers):
    return reduce(truediv, numbers)


def subtract(*numbers):
    return reduce(sub, numbers)

divide(4, 2, 1)
2.0

subtract(4, 2, 1)
1

subtract(100, 6)
94
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I only asked for the subtraction, but thanks.

Comment: We do go above and beyond ;)